# COALESCE return single value when user order by datecolumn in query

Tags: sql-server

I am using coalesce function to get all values for particular project and it is working as expected

```
DECLARE @strTaskName varchar(Max);

SELECT @strTaskName = COALESCE(@strTaskName+',',' ') + '"' + TaskName + '"' 
FROM TableA 
WHERE Project_Id = 'Project1'
```

It is returning a result:

```
Task1,Task2,Task3,Task4
```

When I used `ORDER BY TaskDate` in the query, it is returning only a single value (`Task4`)

```
SELECT
    @strTaskName = COALESCE(@strTaskName+',',' ') + '"' + TaskName + '"' 
FROM TableA    
WHERE Project_Id = 'Project1' 
ORDER BY TaskDate
```

I want result like this:

```
Task1,Task2,Task3,Task4
```

TableA

```
  TaskName |  TaskDate               | Project_Id
 ----------+-------------------------+------------
  Task1    | 2020-08-21 17:00:00.000 | Project1
  Task2    | 2020-08-21 17:00:00.000 | Project1
  Task3    | 2020-09-03 17:00:00.000 | Project1
  Task4    | 2022-05-30 17:00:00.000 | Project1
```

Comment: Have a look at `STRING_AGG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `@variable = @variable +` string concatenation technique is undefined. An alternative is [`FOR XML`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380) for defined results:

```
DECLARE @strTaskName varchar(Max);
SELECT @strTaskName = STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(TaskName, '"')
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Project_Id ='Project1'
    ORDER BY TaskDate
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

Comment: Not very important, but the OP want `CONCAT(',', TaskName)` instead of `',' + QUOTENAME(TaskName, '"')`.

Comment: @Ilyes, I didn't call it out in my answer but `QUOTENAME(TaskName, '"')` is similar to the original `'"' + TaskName + '"'` query except it will also escape double quotes in the TaskName if present.